# How should an Indian whose primary language is not English start learning German?

Tags: self-learning, online-learning, german

I am an Indian and my primary language is Hindi. English is our secondary language, which we use in college studies and corporate offices. Our daily communications happens through Hindi and our local languages.

My goal is to learn a basic level of German that will help me managing normal conversations. I am a working person who does not have any access to a teacher or contacts who know German. I can invest time in self-learning on weekends.

Considering these points, where should I start learning German?

Answer (score 5):

Your knowledge of English is very helpful in this regard. In your shoes, I would rather learn German using English as a base rather than Hindi.

Find a book or an online resource in English that will teach you German. The reason is that the English language has two major roots; German is one of them (Latin is the other). A majority of the 2,000 most common German words are similar to English equivalents; e.g. Stuhl and stool, Kuhl and cow, Wasser and water. If you can "translate" your knowledge of English into German, you will be well on your way to completing at least the so-called A1 level of proficiency in the [Common European Framework of Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages).

The above is "stopgap" measure until you can get some real instruction, but I have used it for multiple languages between opportunities to get formal training.

Answer (score 3):

I am also a Indian. It is not hard to learn German.

Contrary to what many people believe, this language is easy to learn, especially if you are well-versed with English. English and German are similar in a way that they share the Germanic root. Additionally, thousands of German and English words are closely related.

It's possible you can learn German language by your own. I am telling you some **steps to learn German language by your own:**

1. Hear and Repeat German Letter Sounds
2. Stockpile Some Easy “Framework Words”
3. Expand Your Vocabulary with Nouns, Verbs and Adjectives
4. Start Putting Sentences Together
5. Memorize Reusable German Phrases
6. Watch Movies in German (Dubbed, Then Authentic)
7. Read the News in German
8. Connect with Other German Learners or Speakers

Also for your more reference I am giving you a [link](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/german/how-to-learn-german-by-yourself) where you can know more about how to learn German language **SOLO**.